# State Management in React Native App

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am working on a react native app where I am using `react-navigation`
My requirement is I have 4 different screens like a typical Live scores app

- screen 1 : List of football matches on the day
- screen 2 : Football match page (scorecard, game stats etc)
- screen 3 : Team Home (where matches of a particular team, related news feed etc)
- screen 4 : League Home (like football worldcup, having matches in that league, news etc)

In this app user can go to any Match Page (screen2) from `screen 1` where they can `select 3` or `screen 4` from where they can go to another match `(screen 2)`, like n number of possibilities.

Now the problem is I am using redux which will have a global store, whenever an user goes to a new page particular content will be loaded in the state and if he selects another page of same route, viz... 2 screen2 routes in the stack both will be pointed to same state fragment, but those two screens are of different matches, I want a architectural suggestion for this scenario mainly related to state management

Screen1 -> Screen2 -> Screen3 -> screen2 -> screen4 ->screen3 -> screen2 ......

If screen stack is something like above how can I manage state. PLease provide your valuable suggestions how I can overcome this complexity

Answer (score 1):

Typically I would decouple the route data from the route information by passing something like an `id` field as the second (`navigationState`) parameter:

```
navigation.navigate("MatchPage", { matchId: matchId });
```

And when you're mapping state to props, you can use the second parameter "`ownProps`", which receives the props passed to the underlying component, in this case the `navigationState` argument provided by react-navigation:

```
const matchContainer = connect(
  (state, ownProps) => {
    const id = ownProps.navigation.state.params.matchId;
    const match = state.matches[id];
    return {
      match
    };
  }
);

const MatchPageContainer = matchContainer(MatchPage);
```

In this example, your application state contains an object called `matches`, keyed by `matchId`, that you can use to lookup match-specific information. This is a common practice, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: I do accept with you idea, in fact I tried a similar approach, what if my state for a screen is too big, I'll end up creating the copies of state for every page which will consume lot of resources

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. You must keep the state for each match you have in your navigation stack somewhere - whether it's in Redux or implicitly on the `react-navigation` navigationState, it will consume the same amount of resources.